# Oracle Unknown Exception

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-4.0

Getting a strange Oracle exception thrown on my local box. The app works fine on the test environment, but will not run locally. I have Oracle version 10.2 and 11.2 installed locally, Referenced the 10.2 Oracle.DataAccess.dll(10.2.0.100) in my project. The exception is thrown but there is no message with the exception to help me resolve it. Using C#/.NET 4.0[image]
FOR LARGER IMAGE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8hWg.png

Here's the "Exception Detail" text:

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=""
  StackTrace:
       at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure)
       at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
       at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
       at DomainModel.Concrete.AutherizationRespository.getUser(String sqlCmd) in C:\LocalRepository\Web_Apps\TransferArticulation6\trunk\DomainModel\Concrete\AutherizationRespository.cs:line 38
       at DomainModel.Concrete.AutherizationRespository.GetAdminUser(String netId) in C:\LocalRepository\Web_Apps\TransferArticulation6\trunk\DomainModel\Concrete\AutherizationRespository.cs:line 30
       at TransferArticulation4.Controllers.AccountController.SecondaryAuthentication(String userNetId) in C:\LocalRepository\Web_Apps\TransferArticulation6\trunk\TransferArticulation\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 117
       at TransferArticulation4.Controllers.AccountController.Logon(FormCollection form) in C:\LocalRepository\Web_Apps\TransferArticulation6\trunk\TransferArticulation\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 84
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__a()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException:
```

The Stack Trace text:

```
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at DomainModel.Concrete.AutherizationRespository.getUser(String sqlCmd) in C:\LocalRepository\Web_Apps\TransferArticulation6\trunk\DomainModel\Concrete\AutherizationRespository.cs:line 38
   at DomainModel.Concrete.AutherizationRespository.GetAdminUser(String netId) in C:\LocalRepository\Web_Apps\TransferArticulation6\trunk\DomainModel\Concrete\AutherizationRespository.cs:line 30
   at TransferArticulation4.Controllers.AccountController.SecondaryAuthentication(String userNetId) in C:\LocalRepository\Web_Apps\TransferArticulation6\trunk\TransferArticulation\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 117
   at TransferArticulation4.Controllers.AccountController.Logon(FormCollection form) in C:\LocalRepository\Web_Apps\TransferArticulation6\trunk\TransferArticulation\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 84
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__a()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

I should also mention that I can get it to run locally if I reference the version 11.2 Oracle.DataAccess.dll(4.112.2.0), but then it doesn't work on the testing server.

Comment: yah, its weird that they don't let it expand... I'll figure another way to post

Comment: no, Inner Exception shows null

Comment: `[.Number,.Source,.Procedure]` all throws `System.NullReferenceException`. I got that from your image

Comment: Have you setup your TNS entries correctly on your local box?